# Toggle menu on page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to toggle menu bar on scroll?
What I have currently:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var nav = $('#topmenuhidden');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      nav.addClass('#menushow');
    } else {
      nav.removeClass("#menushow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh; /* just to force some scrollbars for demo */
}

#topmenuhidden {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_wrapper" id="topmenuhidden">
  <div class="menu" id="menushow">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="barishband.html">Barish Band</a></li>
      <li><a href="upcomingevents.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="ourclients.html">Our Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `nav.removeClass("#menushow");` --> `"#menushow"` is not a class. ".menushow" is, but using it inside a `.removeClass()` method you don't need the `.` class prefix, simply use the className.

Answer (score 0):

Define a special class `.visible { /* styles here */ }`  in CSS with the desired styles and toggle it with JavaScript:

```js
const elMenu = document.querySelector("#menu");

const handleMenu = () => {
  const { scrollY } = window;
  elMenu.classList.toggle("visible", scrollY > 100);
};

addEventListener("resize", handleMenu);
addEventListener("scroll", handleMenu);
handleMenu();
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body{
  min-height: 300vh; /* demo scrollbars */
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #0bf;
  
  transition: 0.3s;
  translate: 0 -100%;
  
  &.visible {
    translate: 0 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  MY MENU
</nav>

Scroll down...
```

using jQuery:

```js
// jQuery example:
const $menu = $('#menu');
const $win = $(window);
const handleMenu = () => {
  $menu.toggleClass("visible", $win.scrollTop() > 200 );
};
$win.on("scroll resize", handleMenu);
handleMenu();
```